# Will a windows reset erase everything in the root of C:\?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset

I want to reset Windows 10 I don't have enough space to copy GTA V and ARK over to a new harddrive (~180gb worth of space) so I'm wondering if I move those files up to root level will windows reset erase all the contents or if it will leave that alone because its' the highest level in the drive. If it will reset C:\ is there a way to change the permissions to have it persist through a system reset?

Comment: Yes, Of course it will.  Only your personal files which exist within your profile directory can be kept but only if you indicate you want to keep your personal.  See my numerous answers on how Reset works on Windows 8+ for more information

Comment: But I want to get rid of all the other junk that is in my personal finals I just don't want to have to re download 180gb worth of content for games that I play often. I thought about making a partition for it but I don't have enough free space on my drive to make a partition to hold both of the games and none of my removable media is big enough

Comment: If they are in the root directory they will be deleted otherwise if they are in the Program Files directory which is the default location for Steam games, they will be transferred to Windows.Old but you will still need to install Steam again.  Sounds like you should go and get a large enough removable storage device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the system reset, really.

When you initiate a `Reset this PC`, it will first ask you what kind of reset you want.

There are 3 options:

1. Keep my programs and files
2. Keep only my files
3. Remove everything.

Although the 3rd option sounds really bad, it will only touch the C partition, not any other partitions you have. If you were to choose this option, you would indeed lose your files.

Options 1 and 2 will however only work on the Windows folder and some folders in Program Files. In the case for 1 and 2, it will move everything it wants to delete to c:\windows.old in folders named after its original location, eg: c:\windows.old\Program Files.

It will keep the files there for a month or until it needs diskspace.

In any case, you will want to reset using option 1 and see if that is enough.

Make sure to make backups of the most important files though, such as savegames, documents, etc. It should be preserved, but you never know.

Comment: I've accumulated a ton of junk on my c:\ within the year so I want to get rid of everything except for these 2 games totaling 180ish gb in size my raid 0 setup only allows 240gb of space in total so I can't put it on a new partition as I dont have the free space to set one up

Comment: What's wrong with deleting the files manually and uninstalling the programs manually?

Comment: I think I'm going to start with that until I clear up enough space for a partition and keep expanding it as I move chunks of the game over and move it all back when the system reset is finished. Just to clarify: reset will not touch any other partition even if it is created through the windows disk management tool?

Comment: Indeed. A reset only works its magic on the partition windows is installed.